# Xcode inferring namespace?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clang, standards

```
namespace Foo {
  class Bar { };
}

namespace Foo {
  namespace Foo {
    class FooFooClass {
      public:
        void do_stuff(Bar& key);
    };
  }
}

using namespace Foo::Foo;

void FooFooClass::do_stuff(Bar& key) {

}
```

The preceding snippet compiles in XCode, but does not compile in Visual Studio (fails on 3rd to last line with `'Bar': undeclared identifier`) which one is more correct according to the C++ Standard.  I'm assuming that clang is inferring the correct namespace for `Bar` in a proprietary non-standard-following way?

Comment: GCC 7.0.1 also has it working so it may be MSVC's fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clang is correct, due to an obscure but useful rule in the standard ([basic.lookup.qual]/3):

> In a declaration in which the *declarator-id* is a *qualified-id*, names used before the *qualified-id* being declared
>   are looked up in the defining namespace scope; names following the *qualified-id* are looked up in the scope
>   of the member’s class or namespace.

That is, as soon as the compiler sees that the entity being defined, `FooFooClass::do_stuff`, is a member of a class, it looks up all following names in that declaration in the scope of `FooFooClass`. That means lookup of `Bar` starts by looking for a member of `Foo::Foo::FooFooClass`, then a member of `Foo::Foo`, then a member of `Foo`, then the global scope. Since `Bar` is found in `Foo`, the name lookup succeeds.